# package manager for docker container running image busybox:uclibc

Tags: docker, busybox, uclibc

I want to install net-tools on one of my running containers, which is running [busybox:uclibc](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/busybox/) image. But this image doesn't have any package manager like ***apt-get*** or ***apk***. Is there a way to do it or should I just make changes to my image?

Answer (score 2):

Anything based on [Busybox](https://busybox.net) doesn't have a package manager.  It's a single binary with a bunch of symlinks into it, and the way to add software to it is to write C code and recompile.  That is, `/bin/busybox` literally *is* `ls` and `sed` and `sh` and `cp` and ...

Comment: Thanks David. Is there any hack that you can suggest to install few network/ system tools like _net-tools_ and _procps_ without me trying to write & compile C code for those binaries. Maybe a ready made repo with all the binaries that I require in one place(I know I'm not that lucky to find them in one place, but I can wish). I tried to install normal binaries using **dpkg**, but it didn't work (dependency issues).

Comment: Use a more full-featured Docker base image like `ubuntu:18.04`.

Comment: Actually I'm using the pre-built image [prom/prometheus](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus/) in my environment, which is derived from busybox and wanted to troubleshoot a networking issue within my container.