# The problem with npm start to start the node app in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, signals, alpine-linux

I read some *Docker and Node.js Best Practices* articles, e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md or [10 best practices to containerize Node.js web applications with Docker](https://snyk.io/blog/10-best-practices-to-containerize-nodejs-web-applications-with-docker/) or [Dockerfile good practices for Node and NPM](https://adambrodziak.pl/dockerfile-good-practices-for-node-and-npm). All these article were written or updated at least in 2021, I don't list the articles written before 2021 but there quite some.

They are all against `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`. The main reason  is npm will **swallow** the exit signals such as SIGTERM and SIGINT, so the graceful shutdown code in my node app won't run.

I guess it was the case for the old npm (although I didn't test it), but I have tested node14+npm6 and node16+npm8 and I can verify that npm6/8 do **NOT** swallow those events and my graceful shutdown code is run. Not sure if that was because npm fixed it.

So the only problem remains is there is 1 more process, npm, to run, i.e. NPM run as **PID 1**. Some articles said the problem with that is "PID 1 will not respond to SIGINT" but as I have verified that is not the case.

Many articles (e.g. this [nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)) suggest just `CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]` but also in https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#handling-kernel-signals said "Node.js process running as PID 1 will not respond to SIGINT (CTRL-C) and similar signals.", i.e. nodejs own documents **contradict** themselves (but I do see nodejs as PID 1 responds to SIGINT)

So I am confused with the problem with `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` or `CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]`

For my app there is 1 more consideration, my npm scripts has pre hook to make the app run correctly, I have `prestart` npm script to make `npm start` work. So currently I just use `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` but I am confused with the "best practice" of how to start my node app in docker.

---  update ---

I found this closed issue for npm [lifecycle: propagate SIGTERM to child](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10868)

So they **did** fix it but the latest comment in that issue was in **2017**, which said "**Yes, this isn’t working, at least with bash**; npm runs its lifecycle processes in a shell, and bash doesn’t forward SIGTERM to its children."

I realize I only tested that on my mac and on our CentOS server, and the alpine based docker. It may also because I use exec form, not shell form in CMD so I got the exit signal.

[Graceful shutdown with Node.js and Kubernetes](https://blog.risingstack.com/graceful-shutdown-node-js-kubernetes/) said their alpine image didn't get SIGTERM using `npm start`, while I test on alpine3.15 and I can get.

Comment: If you've demonstrated in your own environment that `npm run start` works the way you expect it to, I don't think there's anything wrong with using it.  The broader Unix statement is that process 1 must explicitly subscribe to SIGINT and SIGTERM to receive them, and they're ignored otherwise.

Comment: So many articles are wrong or outdated about `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` makes my wonder why. I am afraid I missed something here, part of reason I asked the question.

Comment: @DavidMaze I was hit by this problem again. Check my answer. So even nodejs official document is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

### with NPM:

```
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

check the process graph on docker container

```
$ ps ajxf
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
    0     1     1     1 pts/0        1 Ssl+     0   0:01 npm run start
    1    19     1     1 pts/0        1 S+       0   0:00 sh -c -- node server.js
   19    20     1     1 pts/0        1 Sl+      0   0:00  \_ node server.js
```

the `npm` process shawns a `shell` process, which then spawns the `node` process. This means that `npm` does not spawn the `node` process as a direct child.

causes the `npm` process to fail to pass signals to the `node` process.

**this is different than how `npm` behaves locally, where it spawns the `node` process directly.**

### with node

```
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

process graph

```
$ ps ajxf
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
    0     1     1     1 pts/0        1 Ssl+     0   0:00 node server.js
```

> Node.js was not designed to run as PID 1 which leads to unexpected behaviour when running inside of Docker. For example, a Node.js process running as PID 1 will not respond to SIGINT (CTRL-C) and similar signals

### solution:

```
CMD [ "bash", "-c", "node server.js" ]
```

Or use the `tini`/`s6` init system

Answer (score 2):

I hit the problem that my docker doesn't respond to the SIGINT signal. After investigation I find that all the node dockers based on **debian**, e.g. 18 (or 18-bookworm), 18-slim (or 18-bookworm-slim), 18-bullseye, 18-bullseye-slim, 18-buster,18-buster-slim do not respond to the SIGINT signal.

I also find that even I use `node server.js` instead of `npm start`, they still do not respond to the SIGINT signal. So it seems that it is NOT npm swallows the SIGINT signal but debian.

I have tested all **alpine** based docker from node 14+ and they all respond to the SIGINT signal if I use **npm instead of node**. So for me that is another reason to choose alpine based image instead of the debian based slim image.

But I find that when using **alpine** based docker, if my CMD is `CMD ["node", "server.js"]` it still can't not respond to the SIGINT signal while `CMD ["npm", "start"]` always respond to the SIGINT signal.

Then I found that the article "Dockerizing a Node.js web app"
on https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/, who suggested to use `CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]` was **deleted** while https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#handling-kernel-signals who said "Node.js process running as PID 1 will not respond to SIGINT", **remains**. In my question I said they **contradict** each other.

But https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#cmd (the **same** doc) still says `CMD ["node","index.js"]`, "it causes exit signals such as SIGTERM and SIGINT to be received by the Node.js process instead of npm swallowing them.". That is **NOT** correct thru my test and even nodejs official document is confusing and still **contradicts** each other.

When using `docker init` to create a template Dockerfile, it also uses `CMD npm start`, check https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/containerize/ for further details.

Answer (score 0):

To work around the swallow of SIGINT and SIGTERM, I do this:

```
CMD [ "bash", "-c", "npm run db:migrate && node ./dist/server/index.js" ]
```

where `npm run db:migrate && node ./dist/server/index.js` was the content of my `npm start`

Comment: As I said in my question the swallow do not happen in MacOS, CentOS and the alpine based docker. So where did you hit the swallow ?

Comment: On an Ubuntu 22.04 VPS. I arrived here looking for issues of Docker CMD not forwarding SIGTERM and SIGINT to my node app, just thought I would complete this thread.