# Nodemon in Docker Container does not stop correctly

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker config.

Docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "rbac-server"
    container_name: rbac-app
    ports:
      - 4000:8080
    environment:
      PORT: 8080
      DB_USER: "dev"
      DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      DB_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      DB_PORT: 3308
      DB_NAME: "testdb"
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      # track the code changes of current directory
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: rbac-db
    image: docker.io/library/mariadb:10.6
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    environmesetupnt:
      MARIADB_USER: dev
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_DATABASE: testdb

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Docker file

```
FROM node:20.8.0-alpine3.18

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ARG PORT=8080
ARG DB_USER
ARG DB_PASSWORD
ARG DB_HOST
ARG DB_PORT
ARG DB_NAME
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

EXPOSE ${PORT}

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Run the app
CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
```

The `npm run dev` script

```
    "dev": "nodemon",
```

---

The Docker containers work and the application is updated when code changes using Nodemon.

However, the `docker compose down` does not exit the Node application correctly. It takes over 10 seconds, which is the default limit, to kill the process via SIGKILL. The logs show `exited with code 0`.

This is not the expected behavior. The `docker stop` command uses the SIGTERM by default to stop the container and Nodemon should pass that signal to the child process, the Node app.

Although I have listened to the SIGTERM and SIGINT signals, the callbacks are not called.

```js
  process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown(server)) // the callback is not called

  process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown(server))
```

Without using Nodemon, the container is stopped correctly in 0.5 seconds. So this is the Nodemon problem.

Are there any workarounds to stop the container that uses Nodemon correctly without being fall back to SIGKILL?

Comment: Do you actually need to run Nodemon in a container?  Or could you for example `docker-compose up -d db` to start only the database, and use Nodemon directly on the host?

Comment: Running Nodemon directly on my host machine means I have to set up all the variables environment and config locally. It is hard to share the correct config with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

While searching for an answer, I found this other post: [The problem with npm start to start the node app in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72709753/the-problem-with-npm-start-to-start-the-node-app-in-docker).

So, basically, when npm scripts are run inside a Docker container, it does not generate the node process as its child, and so it can't pass either SIGTERM or SIGINT to the process.

The solution is to call the scripts that are run by npm directly.

Assuming you're using nodemon to start index.js, you should replace

```
npm run dev
```

with

```
./node_modules/.bin/nodemon index.js
```